# Compile[] with non-numeric arguments

Tags: compile

Suppose I have a function like this `foo[x_]:=Switch[x, "dog", Sin[0.17], "cat", Cos[0.18], "frog", 17]`. Compiling it won't work, since the argument is a string. Obviously, one can manually encode the set of possible input strings as numbers, possibly with the help of `FeatureExtraction`, but is there any fully automatic (or programmatic, if you prefer) way of dealing with this?

Comment: With an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) `<|"dog" -> Sin[0.17], "cat" -> Cos[0.18], "frog" -> 17|>`? Try not to focus on compilation before exhausting built-in functions.

Comment: @Roman You seem to be missing the point. The "real" function would be a lot more complicated, so each entry in the association would be very slow. Yes, one can compile each branch into a separate function, but then the dispatch would still be interpreted, so the result would be both ugly and slow.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a list of string/function pairs

```
L = {{"dog", (Pause[1]; #) &},
     {"cat", (Pause[1]; #)^2 &},
     {"frog", (Pause[1]; #)^3 &}};
```

this will automatically generate a precompiled [`Dispatch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html) table to make the lookup super-fast:

```
Clear[foo];
(foo[#[[1]]] = #[[2]]) & /@ L;
```

Test:

```
?foo
(*    definitions    *)

foo["cat"][5]
(*    25    *)

foo["frog"][5]
(*    125    *)
```

If the functions in `L` are uncompiled, you can also compile them while assigning them to `foo`:

```
Clear[foo];
(foo[#[[1]]] = Compile[x, Evaluate[#[[2]][x]]]) & /@ L;
?foo
```

Comment: Aha! Now you are talking! That is very cool!